# Redirect a div id to other div id in a same page?

Tags: redirect, html

Someone Please help me in redirecting a user from one div id to other div id after the particular div id is enabled it should redirect after 3 seconds to other div id

Comment: what programming language? your question still uncomplete, so its hard to understand.

Comment: please attempt to use the correct terminology or give the big picture, the following phrases do not make sense: "id is enabled" "redirect to an id", the following phrases are used in the incorrect context: "redirecting" "div id"

Answer (score 2):

#### HTML

```
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
window.location.hash = 'b';
```